# jquery break .each

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have a form, and he contains textfields to percent data, on click in submit i want to validate all percent using a class selector on each, and on check invalid percent break each and focus field, but the 'return false' dont break this

my code:

```
$('#enviarquestionario').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

        $('input.percent').each(function(){
            valor = $(this).val();
            if(isNaN(valor) || valor > 100 || valor < 0 ){
                alert('Preencha corretamente os campos de porcentagem com valores entre 0 e 100');
                $(this).focus();
                return false;
            }else{
                $('#questionarioparticipacao').submit();
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

Somehow the form is being submitted.

```
 #enviarquestionario is a ancor
```

Comment: If the form is submitted, your if statement fails. Also, submitting a form inside an each loop does'nt seem like a great idea ?

Comment: With the above code, your if statement failing is the *only* way your form will be submitted.

Comment: Form will be submitted on first valid percent number.
The easiest way to do this would be to create a flag before 'each' loop, and set inside the loop.
After the loop using this flag you can decide whether to submit or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
$('#enviarquestionario').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var isError = false;

    $('input.percent').each(function(){
        valor = $(this).val();
        if(isNaN(valor) || valor > 100 || valor < 0 ){
            alert('Preencha corretamente os campos de porcentagem com valores entre 0 e 100');
            $(this).focus();
            isError = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(!isError){ $('#questionarioparticipacao').submit(); }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your code to use a valid flag which is set to false even if one validation fails:

```
$('#enviarquestionario').click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var valid = true; // initially set to true

        $('input.percent').each(function(){
            valor = $(this).val();
            if(isNaN(valor) || valor > 100 || valor < 0 ){
                alert('Preencha corretamente os campos de porcentagem com valores entre 0 e 100');
                $(this).focus();
                valid = false; // set to false even if one fails
                return false;
            }
        });

        // submit only if all validations pass
        if(valid === true) $('#questionarioparticipacao').submit();

        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my version. This will actually break the .each like you wanted.

```
$('#enviarquestionario').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        var breakerbreaker = false;
        $('input.percent').each(function(){
            if(breakerbreaker){ return false; }

            valor = $(this).val();
            if(isNaN(valor) || valor > 100 || valor < 0 ){
                alert('Preencha corretamente os campos de porcentagem com valores entre 0 e 100');
                $(this).focus();
                breakerbreaker = true;
        });

    if(!breakerbreaker){ $('#questionarioparticipacao').submit(); }    
    return false;
});
```